# Calling a static inline function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

How do I call this `static inline` function?

```
static inline int xGradient(uchar* image, int x, int y)
{
    return ((int)(image[y-1, x-1])) +
        2*image[y, x-1] +
        image[y+1, x-1] -
        image[y-1, x+1] -
        2*image[y, x+1] -
        image[y+1, x+1];
}

static inline int yGradient(uchar* image, int x, int y)
{
    return ((int)(image[y-1, x-1])) +
        2*image[y-1, x] +
        image[y-1, x+1] -
        image[y+1, x-1] -
        2*image[y+1, x] -
        image[y+1, x+1];
```

I get trouble when I call the function. I call it like this :

```
gx = xGradient(&data[ii], x,y);
gy = yGradient(&data[ii], x,y);
sum = abs(gx) + abs(gy);
sum = sum > 255 ? 255:sum;
sum = sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;
```

I dont get the result of gx and gy. Help me to calculate `gx` and`gy` in the program above.

> this my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<omp.h>
#include<ctime>
#include<cmath>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

static inline int xGradient(uchar* image, int x, int y)
{
return ((int)(image[y-1, x-1])) +
        2*image[y, x-1] +
        image[y+1, x-1] -
        image[y-1, x+1] -
        2*image[y, x+1] -
        image[y+1, x+1];
}

static inline int yGradient(uchar* image, int x, int y)
{
return ((int)(image[y-1, x-1])) +
        2*image[y-1, x] +
        image[y-1, x+1] -
        image[y+1, x-1] -
        2*image[y+1, x] -
        image[y+1, x+1];
}

int main()  
 {
 Mat src, grey, grey2, dst;
 clock_t start, finish;
 int gx, gy, sum;
 size_t total;
 int sizes[2];
 start = clock();

 src= imread("E:/sobel/Debug/view_sea.bmp");
 imwrite("E:/sobel/Debug/Serial/Citra Asli.bmp", src );

 cvtColor(src,grey,CV_BGR2GRAY);
 imwrite("E:/sobel/Debug/Serial/Grayscale.bmp", grey );

 dst = grey.clone();
 if( !grey.data )
 {
     return -1;
 }

 total=grey.total();
 cv::Size s = grey.size();
 sizes[0] = s.height;
 sizes[1] = s.width;
 cout << "citra terdiri dari " << total << " piksel dengan ukuran " << sizes[0] << " x " << sizes[1] << " piksel" << endl;

int starty=(grey.rows);
if(starty==0)
{starty=1;}
int stopy=(grey.rows);
if(stopy>grey.rows - 1)
{stopy=grey.rows - 1;}

int ii=grey.cols;
uchar* data=grey.data;

 for(int y = starty; y < stopy; y++)
{
    ii++;
    for(int x = 1; x < sizes[1] - 1; x++)
     {
         gx = xGradient(&data[ii], x,y);
         gy = yGradient(&data[ii], x,y);
         sum = abs(gx) + abs(gy);
         sum = sum > 255 ? 255:sum;
         sum = sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;
         data[ii] = sum;
        ii++;

    }
     ii++;
}

 finish = clock();

 imwrite( "E:/sobel/Debug/Serial/Output sobel dengan Serial.bmp", src);

 cout << "Waktu Eksekusi Deteksi Tepi Serial adalah : " << float(finish-  start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " detik" << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

> i got wrong in this code

```
int ii=grey.cols;
uchar* data=grey.data;

 for(int y = starty; y < stopy; y++)
{
    ii++;
    for(int x = 1; x < sizes[1] - 1; x++)
     {
         gx = xGradient(&data[ii], x,y);
         gy = yGradient(&data[ii], x,y);
         sum = abs(gx) + abs(gy);
         sum = sum > 255 ? 255:sum;
         sum = sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;
         data[ii] = sum;
        ii++;

    }
     ii++;
}
```

Comment: Define "don't get the results of gx and gy" Does it not print? Or are you getting a value you didn't expect? Also `inline` won't change the behavior of your program, it's just an optimization thing ( that your compiler can choose to ignore )

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "don't get the result of gx and gy"? Like in not the result you expect? Can you please edit the question to show what you expect, and what you actually get? What is `data`? What is `ii`? What is `x` and `y`? What are the declarations *and* the values of all those variables? Also, have you tried to step through the code in a debugger to see what it really does?

Comment: amazing, that it even compiles, given the image[y-1, x] bs.

Comment: @berak It's the simple [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). Not that it makes sense it the context of the code shown, but it's still a valid expression.

Comment: yea, right, so only the right side of the comma gets evaluated

Comment: what should i do, to call the function? gx = xGradient(&data[ii], x,y);how to compute gx with the code program above. i got wrong at gx = xGradient(&data[ii], x,y);
gy = yGradient(&data[ii], x,y); i think i must change &data[ii] but i dont know what should i use to change &data[ii]

Answer (score 4):

i think, you confused python/numpy  and c++ syntax here.

while `image[y-1, x-1]` would do the proper job in python ( given a 2d numpy array ) ,

in c++, where you only got a 1d uchar array, it boils down to `image[x-1]` . not what you expected, probably.

to do it right, also your function needs an additional param, the size of 1 row (width):

```
static inline int xGradient(uchar* image, int x, int y, int W)
{
    return (
        image[ W*(y-1) + (x-1)] +
        2*image[ W*(y) + (x-1)] +
        image[ W*(y+1) + (x-1)] -
        image[ W*(y-1) + (x+1)] -
        2*image[ W*(y) + (x+1)] -
        image[ W*(y+1) + (x+1)] );
}
```

but again, since we're in opencv, why not use the Mat object itself, instead of raw bytes :

```
static inline int xGradient(const Mat & img, int x, int y)
{
    return (
        img.at<uchar>( (y-1) , (x-1) ) +
        2*img.at<uchar>( (y) , (x-1) ) +
        img.at<uchar>( (y+1) , (x-1) ) -
        img.at<uchar>( (y-1) , (x+1) ) -
        2*img.at<uchar>( (y) , (x+1) ) -
        img.at<uchar>( (y+1) , (x+1) ) );
}
// and call it : 
Mat img;
int xg = xGradient(img,x,y);
```

and remember, when applying this you have to leave out a 1 pixel border in your image, else you go out of bounds ...

Comment: i got trouble how to get the value of xGradient and ygradient. what should i do to call the function did you write?

Comment: because i want use uchar*. how to call uchar from xGradient?